# Superscript and subscript in R

Tags: r

I was trying to do a super script after a subscript. See image. But with this code:

```
xlab=expression(-log ~ K[TX]^{-1})
```

it put the supercript above K instead of after the TX. so basically I want the -1 to be the supercript of the whole (K[TX])^-1. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do

```
xlab=expression(-log ~ {K[TX]}^{-1})
```

or, alternatively:

```
xlab=expression(-log ~ K[TX^{-1}])
```

The second is exactly what you are asking for, but it may be more difficult to read.

Test them [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=9N04Q4yJ&version=1)

Comment: Great site. I'd never heard of it.